# Serialize SortedList to an object array and remove key/value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize JSON to normal format without key/value, but unfortunately the provided class adds key and value strings to the JSON file.
Here is my Post method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PostTest()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.Headers.Add("X-My-Header", "success");

    MyCaseRequest data = new MyCaseRequest()
    {
        Name = "TestAgre",
        ExpirationDateTime = "2016-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        Signatories = new List<SignatoryRequest>
        {
            new MyRequest() { Type = MyType.Comp, Id = "11111" },
            new MyRequest() { Type = MyType.Per, Id = "2222" }
        },
        Documents = new SortedList<string, ThingsRequest>()
        {
            {"0" , new ThingsRequest() { Name = "Test",  Description = "Short description about", Length = 4523 }},
            {"1" , new ThingsRequest() { Name = "Test1",  Description = "short description about", Length = 56986 }}
        }
    };

    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver();

    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);

    var statusCode = sendJsonDemo.SendJsonDemo(json);
}
```

and here is my class which serializes the sorted dictionary to an object array:

```
class DictionaryAsArrayResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(IDictionary) ||
                (i.IsGenericType &&
                 i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))))
         {
             return base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
         }

         return base.CreateContract(objectType);
     }
}
```

and here is my output:

```
{
  "Name": "TestAgreement",
  "ExpirationDateTime": "2016-07-14T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Signatories": [
    {
      "Type": "Comp",
      "Id": "11111"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Per",
      "Id": "2222"
    }
  ],
  "Documents": [
    {
      "Key": "0",
      "Value": {
        "Name": "Test",
        "Description": "Short description about",
        "Length": 4523
      }
    },
    {
      "Key": "1",
      "Value": {
        "Name": "Test1",
        "Description": "short description about",
        "Length": 56986
      }
    }
  ],
  "Metadata": []
}
```

Comment: It looks like this isn't really ASP.NET-specific, so it would be best if you could provide a [mcve] console app which lets us reproduce the problem. Next, you've shown the output you *are* getting, which makes sense as a `SortedList` is a key/value map, sorted by key. Did you expect it to just be an array in JSON? If so, you should use `List<>` instead of `SortedList<,>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change Documents property to a `IEnumerable<ThingsRequest>` so it will not have key / values.

If you have a SortedList as input, you can do that to get it as a simple `IEnumerable<ThingsRequest>` (but still ordered) : `Documents.Values`.

Comment: Well, I have tried, but unfortunately it didn't worked, with IEnumerable there was key and values strings in JSON file.

Comment: I use that in my own projects, and there is no key values with this. Are you sure to serialize `Documents.Values` or things like that instead of your OrderedList ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what JSON you are expecting to get, as you didn't show us in your question.  You said you wanted "normal format without key/value", which is a bit vague. 
`SortedList<K, V>` implements `IDictionary<K, V>`, and the "normal" serialization format for a dictionary is like this:

```
{
  "Documents": {
    "0": {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Description": "Short description about",
      "Length": 4523
    },
    "1": {
      "Name": "Test1",
      "Description": "short description about",
      "Length": 56986
    }
  }
}
```

In your code, you are using a custom resolver to change the contract for all dictionaries to a `JsonArrayContract`.  This tells Json.Net to serialize the `SortedList` as an array of key-value pairs, which is precisely why you are getting "Key" and "Value" properties in your output.  If you want the "normal" output, then don't use the resolver to change the contract.

However, I *suspect* that what you're really looking for is just a plain array of items like you would get with a regular `List<T>`:

```
{
  "Documents": [
    {
      "Name": "Test",
      "Description": "Short description about",
      "Length": 4523
    },
    {
      "Name": "Test1",
      "Description": "short description about",
      "Length": 56986
    }
  ]
}
```

If so, you can use a custom `JsonConverter` instead of a resolver to get this output.  Here is the code you would need for the converter:

```
class DictionaryToValuesArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IDictionary).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IDictionary dict = (IDictionary)value;
        JArray array = JArray.FromObject(dict.Values);
        array.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

<sub>Note: this converter only handles serializing, not deserializing.  If you need to go the full round-trip, you will need to implement `ReadJson` as well, which is beyond the scope of this answer.</sub>

To use the converter, add it to the `Converters` collection in the  `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new DictionaryToValuesArrayConverter());
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);
```

Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HFeXLC